# How can I make whois talking about the domain I asked only?

Tags: networking, internet, dns, domain, whois

For example, `whois =APAEB.COM` says

```
Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Server Name: APAEB.COM.BR
   Registrar: ENOM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.enom.com
   Referral URL: http://www.enom.com

>>> Last update of whois database: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 08:18:54 UTC <<<
```

I do not want to see what is going on in .br zone. Am I wrong in my assumption that '=' character in front of domain means I only want to hear about the domain in question and no any other domain? And if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The result you get depend on the whois server you asking, and each whois server can work differently.

In the above query it's looks like that the only domain registered which contain the name APAEB.COM is APAEB.COM.BR.

Whois have a list of default whois server it will query based on there TLD (contry code, com ... etc), and it seems like the one you accessing is VeriSign whois database (which manage .com), and the way VeriSign whois works looks like a string search and not a domain lookup.

try this for example, `echo '=APAEB' | nc whois.verisign-grs.com 43` and see who many result you will get.